# A podcast subscription/managing app that syncs between PC and Android.

Tags: android, web-browser, podcast

What I'm wanting is a service I can use to *listen to podcasts on my android phone* but download the podcasts using my web browser.

Essentially on the weekends, or in the evenings I want to be able to search and find interesting podcasts (being able to listen to them at this time would be good), add them to playlists or whatever, and then those be *downloaded* (so I don't need to use my mobile data) to my phone for listening to at work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's an exact dupe, but I'd already written it and I thought it's still worth submitting. Different search terms, etc.

Comment: I tend to agree with what you say, but I'm not sure what others here think. Well, in any case, first of all look at my answer there and see if the solution works for you...

Comment: @mguassa What I was getting at is that this quesiton should be closed as dupe and point the other question. re: your answer, it looks good but the problem is I don't have a credit card at the moment so I can't buy the app.

Comment: The app [AntennaPod](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.danoeh.antennapod) and the service [gpodder.net](https://gpodder.net/) are both free, you don't need to buy them (no need for a credit card).